# How to show two groups are isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

For any abelian group $A$ and a positive integer $m$ prove that
$$
Hom(\mathbb{Z}_{m},A)\cong{A[m]=\{a\in{A}|ma=0\}}.
$$

I am not sure how to start to do this problem.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You need to define a map in one direction.  Then, show that it's **(1)** a homomorphism, **(2)** injective, and **(3)** surjective.

Comment: There is no mention of $R$ after the first sentence... Anyway, what is a homomorphism $\mathbb Z_m \rightarrow A$ completely determined by? (Or in more generality, given a cyclic group $C_n$, a homomorphism $C_n \rightarrow A$ is completely determined by...)

Comment: I know this! :)

But what's that map?

Comment: I think they dont ask you to show that $Z_m$ and A are isomorphic, but that the homeomorphisms from $Z_m$ into A are homeomorphic to ${a \in A ...}$

Comment: @Thomas Indeed, but see WLOG's answer below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, since it may give you a good sense of why exact sequences are so computationally powerful:

There is an exact sequence

$$0\to\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\times m}\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\to 0$$

Homing this with $A$ gives

$$0\to \text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z},A)\to \text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},A)\to\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},A)$$

But, this is clearly the same as

$$0\to \text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z},A)\to A\xrightarrow{\times m}A$$

So

$$\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z},A)\cong \ker(A\xrightarrow{\times m}A)=A[m]$$

Comment: I think $Hom(-,A)$ is left exact, so in your sequence the $0$ should be on the left

Comment: Yes, the covariant functor $Hom(-,A)$ is left exact and we don't know whether $A$ is $Z$-module or not.

Comment: @WLOG You're right, I made a typo :)

Comment: @Algebra The functor you list is contravariant, and an abelian group is, by definition, a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Comment: Oops, sorry! You are absolutely right the functor is contravariant.

Comment: And, I mean we don't know whether $A$ is injective $Z$-module or not?

Comment: @Algebra That doesn't matter though. The Hom functor is always left-exact, we don't need exactness here.

Comment: @Alex Youcis: I understand what you mean. I also really like your arguments which show the beauty of applying Hom to short exact sequences.

Comment: @Alex Youcis: By applying this property (i.e. $A=\mathbb{Z}_{n}$), we have $Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}_{m},\mathbb{Z}_{n})\cong{\mathbb{Z}_{n}[m]}$. But how do establish $Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}_{m},\mathbb{Z}_{n})\cong{\mathbb{Z}_{gcd(m,n)}}$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that a $f \in Hom(\mathbb{Z}_{m},A)$ is determined by $f(1) = a$ because $\mathbb{Z}_{m}$ is cyclic.

The order of $1 \in \mathbb{Z}_{m}$ is $m$, so $ma = 0$ is a necessary condition; but for every $a \in A[m]$ you can define $\phi \in Hom(\mathbb{Z}_{m},A)$ with $\phi(1) = a$, and so is also a sufficient condition.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**  Given $f \in \operatorname{Hom}(\Bbb{Z}_m, A)$, consider $f(1) \in A$.